# How to implement go get within an app that has no internet?

Tags: go

I am playing around with a Go app that imports martini for example. Every time I run the app, I have to run "go get github.com/codegangsta/martini". Any way to NOT have to do this? Either way, how would this work in an offline environment? I am considering Go for an app that will be offline with no internet access.

Comment: It seems unlikely you have to run that command every time you run the app.  That command should fetch the code locally to your machine and make it available for all future runs of the app.  When you app terminates, it should not delete that code.  What goes wrong when you don't run `go get` before running your app?  What commands do you use to run your app?

Answer (score 4):

From the [go documentation](http://golang.org/cmd/go/):

`Get downloads and installs the packages named by the import paths, along with their dependencies.`

To expand on that: 
`go get` will clone the code you're requesting from the repository (in this case `github.com/codegangsta/martini`) as well as any code that that code imports and store it in your local `$GOPATH/src/` directory then build it and store it so that is available to call via `import`, so you should never have to call `go get` more than once unless your `GOPATH` is being changed and it should always be available locally after the initial `go get`.